# Walking throughout syntax tree recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, tree, xml-parsing

I have a sentence which is *syntactically parsed*. For example, "My mom wants to cook". Parsing is **[('My', 1), ('mom', 2), ('wants', -1), ('to', 2), ('cook', 3)]**. The numbers mean the indexes of items the words depend on: 'mom' depends on 'wants' and 'wants' is the second element of the array (starting from zero as usual). 'Wants' has '-1' because that is the core of sentence, it doesn't depend on anything else. ***I need to GET the SUBJECT which is 'my mom' here.*** How can I do this?

To this moment, I have only tried writing loops which work not in every case. The deal is that the subject may consist of more than 2 words, and that number is undefined. Something like this...

'Values' is [('My', 1), ('mom', 2), ('wants', -1), ('to', 2), ('cook', 3)]

```
for indx, value in enumerate(values):
    m = morph.parse(value[0])
    if isinstance(m, list):
        m = m[0]
    if 'NOUN' in m.tag:
        if value[1] == str(index[0]): #it checks if the word (part of the subject) depends on the verb
            terms.append([value[0], indx])

if len(terms) > 0:
    term = terms[0][0]
    t = []
    for indx, value in enumerate(values):
        if value[1] == str(terms[0][1]): #it checks if the word depend on the found part of the subject
            m = morph.parse(value[0])
            if isinstance(m, list):
                m = m[0]
            if 'NOUN' in m.tag:
                t.append([value[0], terms[0][0]])
```

The algorithm should work like this: ***walks the whole array and stops when it finds all the dependencies of the given word and all the dependencies of these dependencies***. (In the example, all the dependencies of 'mom'). Please, help!

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: I am using pymorphy2

Comment: @ЕвгенияРубанова pymorphy2 seems to be for russian and ukrainian, not english though all sentences you gave were english. is there an engine you use for english morphographical analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sorry that I took so long to get back to you.**

I finally figured it out. Code is at the bottom, but I'll explain how it works first:

when `parse(values)` is called it iterates through the sentence in values and calls the recursive `getDepth` for each word. ```getDepth`` computes how many word relations are between a given word and the verb. 
E.g. for "The", depth is 1, because it directly calls the verb.

for "King", it is 2, because "King" calls "The" and "The" calls the verb (**Where call = have a pointer that points to a certain word**)

Once all depths are computed, `parse` finds the word with the highest depth ("France") and uses recursive `traceFrom()` to string together the subject.

All you really care a about is `parse()` which takes the preparsed string like [('My', 1), ('mom', 2), ('wants', -1), ('to', 2), ('cook', 3)] and spits out the complete subject.   ***Works for both examples, but you should test some more.***

```py
values = [('The', 4), ('King', 0), ('of', 1), ('France', 2), ('died', -1)]

#values = [('My', 1), ('mom', 2), ('wants', -1), ('to', 2), ('cook', 3)]

def getDepth(i, s, n = 0):
    print('D is %d' % n)
    if s[i][1] == -1:
        return n
    else:
        return getDepth(s[i][1], s, n+1)

def traceFrom(m, s, dt=[]):
    print('Got n:%d, s:' % m, s)
    if s[m][1] == -1:
        d = []
        n = 0
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if i in dt:
                d.append(s[i][0])
        return " ".join(d)
    else:
        dt.append(m)
        return traceFrom(s[m][1], s, dt)


def parse(sentence):
    d = []
    for i in range(len(sentence)):
        d.append(getDepth(i, sentence))
    m = d.index(max(d))
    print('Largest is ' , d[m], ' of ', d)
    return traceFrom(m, sentence)
print('Subject :', parse(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your preparsed array, this is quite easy:

```py
values = [('My', 1), ('mom', 2), ('wants', -1), ('to', 2), ('cook', 3)]


def parseFrom(n, data):
        if values[n][1] != -1:
                #print('Stepping (%s,%d)' % (values[n][0], values[n][1]))
                data.append(values[n][0])
                return parseFrom(values[n][1], data)
        else:
                #print('At verb')
                return data

subject = ' '.join(parseFrom(0, []))

print('Sentence has subject:', subject)
```

The function is recursive if the current word is not the verb, otherwise returns the subject as an array. *Sorry if it doesn't work on all sentences*

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your decision is really good and works perfectly for my example! But I forgot to mention cases where I need to get all dependencies of the dependecies of the word (which is a part of subject) as well. For example, [('W', 4), ('X', 3), ('Y', 3),('Z', 0), ('VERB', -1)] where the subject is WXYZ. Sorry for this:( I am really dumb at recursive desicions...

Comment: Could you give me a (parsed) sentence as an example?

Comment: Yes, [('The', 4), ('King', 0), ('of', 1), ('France', 2), ('died', -1)] and the subject that I need here is "The King of France".

Comment: what library do you use to preparse the sentences?

Comment: @ЕвгенияРубанова just noticed minor error with your [('W', 4), ('X', 3), ('Y', 3),('Z', 0), ('VERB', -1)] sentence, it gives W X Z, because of the first index rule, looking for fix...